# Sub-menu will not stack vertically

Tags: css

I am trying to vertically stack a sub-menu, however, I am having trouble getting it to stack possibly due to some of the parent styling. The goal is for the sub-menu to stack vertically underneath the very first link. Any advice?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gmtugks5/1/)

CSS

```
nav {
    height: 70px;
    background: transparent;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    height: 70px;
    float:right;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    background: transparent;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    padding-top: 23px;
    height: 43px;
    border-top: 4px solid $White;
  }
  nav ul li:first-child {
    border-top: 4px solid $White;
  }

  nav ul li a {
    font-family: 'Lato', serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: $TextColor;
    line-height: 122%;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  nav ul ul {
    display: block;
  }
  nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
  }
  nav ul ul li a {
    display: block;
  }
```

Comment: I recommend you to have a look at examples on http://www.cssplay.co.uk - that guy is a CSS magician and you are almost guaranteed to find an example that matches your case.

Comment: You should remove the `float` style and don't use it if you don't know what it's for and how it behaves.

Comment: Combining [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) and [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) properties when you don't really understand how they work will create confusing results. I suggest reading through the documentation I've linked.

Answer (score -1):

Man, you really need to **learn** what you are doing. It was quite some effort to correct your code. For a start, you seem to be unaware of the fact that

```
nav ul { ... }
```

will not only affect your outer `<ul>`, but also your inner `<ul id="submenu">`.

The fact that you use `id="submenu"` strongly suggests that the next thing you might be unaware of is that per HTML document, any given id value must be **unique**, that is it can only be used on *one* element.

> https://jsfiddle.net/gmtugks5/2/